# Should flash messages fade out or contain a close button or stay forever?

Tags: messages, messagebox

Note: By flash message, I do not mean Adobe Flash, but messages that should be displayed on completion of an action.

I am designing a web application and messages will be displayed after a certain action.

There are 2 scenarios where this will happen:

- User performs an action such as delete or create new user. After the action is performed, they get redirected to the main view (which in this case would be a list of all users) and a flash message is shown.
- User performs an action such as saving a blog post. After the action is performed, no redirection happens. The user remains on the same page, but a flash message is displayed.

The flash message is just a simple stylized `div`:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv373W.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Problem: What should with the flash message?

- Should the message have a close button to be closed by the user manually?
- Should the message fade out automatically?
- Should the message just remain there permanently and be uncloseable?

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you talking about Adobe Flash or are you referring to 'flash messages' as pointed out by Kit Grose?

Comment: @phpdev Would it be fair to just call these "falsh" messages simply "notifications"?

Comment: I guess its possible to just call them notifications, but there are also other types of notifications (for example "growl" notifications and so on), so I guess Flash Message is just more specific.

Comment: When the flash "messages" aren't user closable (which is more often than not the case), I use browser extensions to close them and sometimes even to prevent them from ever reopening in future visits.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Anything the user will take for granted should fade away.

For example:

- Message has been sent after clicking "send"
- Item has been deleted after clicking "delete"
- Contact has been added after clicking "add"

Items that should remain visible are mission only critical things like:

- Incoming call (someone is waiting for you on the other end and needs your response!)
- Message failed to send after clicking "send"
- Your entire hard drive is being erased in t-60 seconds, 59, 58, 57...

If the user assumes the task has been completed, fade it out. Only show it briefly to reassure them.

Comment: An important consideration with a fading message is to force the space in which the message appears, otherwise you will end up with users who are just about to interact with another part of the page when it all shifts to fill the space left by the fading message!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty conventional to have the flash message fade away, but I'm generally in favour of having it be user-dismissable (provided it also goes away after the next page load).

The reason is simple; timed events are only visible to people who are looking for them during the time their being shown. It also makes copy/pasting the flash message much harder (or even impossible).

If the message can be dismissed easily (as StackExchange does), the user can choose to ignore it, copy it, or close it. It's important that this shouldn't mean users *need* to close the message(s) for fear that they eventually stack up three hundred pixels high.

[image: A screenshot of how StackExchange flash messages appear]

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration is whether or not the message contains any information that the user must make note of.   For example, if the message contains a confirmation number, you don't want the message to automatically disappear.  You want the user to remove the message as an acknowledgement that s/he has seen (and possibly recorded) whatever information was presented.

Answer (score 1):

As answered on [Message Fade Timing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16580/message-fade-timing), you have to consider the importance of the message. Is it something that the user can skip or is it important information?

Just a word about Flash. If you have any interest in reaching mobile users, Flash may not be the best choice. I would go with AJAX and depending my message importance, modal window can do the job. In that the case, this article may help you http://uxmovement.com/forms/modal-and-modeless-windows-best-practices/

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, phpdev wasn't referring to Adobe Flash when he mentions "flash messages"; it's a term for those temporary messages letting you know that your action was successful or not. If you're also referring to those messages, do you have a link to explain why that's not a good option for mobile users?

Comment: Sorry for any misperception. Anyway, just to be sure I will add a comment to @phpdev clarify that for us.

http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/click_online/9636753.stm and http://mashable.com/2011/11/09/its-official-flash-mobile-player-is-dead/

Comment: Ah, you are referring to Adobe Flash. I believe he's referring to [these sorts of flash messages](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/the-notification-tray-at-the-top-of-stack-exchange-sites-what-is-it-called-and). Hopefully @phpdev can clarify.

Comment: I am not talking about adobe flash but "flash messages" as @KitGrose said :)

Answer (score 1):

Designing a fade-out or and auto-close of a message -- a form of "anticipating" behaviour -- is a greater challenge for your design and designers.

I would

1. start with just making it easy to dismiss, and not auto-close it
2. try get a feel for if it is needed make it auto-close, by letting users use it over time,
3. then, if needed,  make it fade away

It all depends on the situation, and on how your users will end up using your system. You would **decrease the risk of failure** -- for example users finding it hard that things are "blinking" too fast or not grasping exactly what happened -- by choosing not to auto-close it.

Related question: [Is it bad design to hide a form's success message after a short time?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18161/is-it-bad-design-to-hide-a-forms-success-message-after-a-short-time)

Answer (score 0):

After any action, if you think the notification message must grab the user's attention, then using a close button would be a good choice.

we could show an background highlighted for the newly added user's row in the users list page (if you are redirecting from the user registration form to users listing page).

Comment: I don't see the correlation between 'grab the users attention' and 'using a close button'. *Why* would a close button be a good choice here? Do you have any reasoning for this?